# WHMCS! - How to get a specific client-group price from MySQL 'tblpricing' table?

Tags: mysql, whmcs

WHMCS! Who knows how to find the price of `domainregister` for a specific client group in the `tblpricing` table? Is there a unique ID I can use?

[image: TBL Pricing Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group id is saved to tsetupfee field, so you can use this SQL statement (for group id = 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tblpricing 
WHERE `tsetupfee` = 2 
AND `type`='domainregister' 
AND `currency`='1' 
AND `relid` = '1'
```